# ¿COMO LOGRO CORRER MI ALGORITMO? NO IDENTIFICO EL ERROR

Tags: algoritmos, matrices, pseint, formulas, pseudocódigo

NECESITO SACAR HIPOTENUSA Y ANGULOS AGUDOS INTERNOS DE UN TRIANGULO RECTANGULO, SOLO CON EL VALOR DE LOS CATETOS, NO SE COMO ALINEAR LA FORMULA DE TANGENTE, ADJUNTO IMAGENES

[image: PROBLEMA INICIAL]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto formateado segun corresponda (si es un error como comentario, si es codigo como codigo),siempre.

Comment: Invierte la declaración `A1 = atan(b)`. La variable SIEMPRE va a la izquierda de la asignación.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.